# add span to wp_nav_menu widget

Tags: menus

Am using the custom menu widget to add a menu in the footer and i want to add a  in the menu how can i do this ?

like so...

```
<li><a href=""><span>menu1</span></a></li>
```

if done it for the main nav using the link before below but as this is a widget am not sure where to add this

```
'link_before' => '<span>',
'link_after' => '</span>'
```

any one know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter `'walker_nav_menu_start_el'` and replace the link text.

Prototype, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse_56028_title' );

function wpse_56028_title( $item )
{
    return preg_replace( '~(<a[^>]*>)([^<]*)</a>~', '$1<span>$2</span></a>', $item);
}
```